# How to set a strict timeout on a Redis cluster operation in Python?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, redis-cluster

I have been working on a Python/Django project and I use uWSGI as my web server.

During the process of responding to a request, some data is retrieved from a Redis cluster using redis-py-cluster. Unfortunately every time when there is a problem in the cluster and it is not responding, due to all uWSGI workers being busy, the whole system breaks down.

Therefor I decided to set a timeout on the cluster operations and prevent them from taking longer than a tolerable amount (10ms in my case).So far i have tried multithreading, that completely failed in a recent cluster incident.

Also I have tried asyncio. There were some recommendations on using run_in_executor which I used and all the same it seems not to respect the timeout that much. Finally there is aredis that provides an async version of StrictRedisCluster from redis-py-cluster. I used that, but it was abnormally consuming CPU and memory so I reverted it immediately.

Here is some code:

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
from rediscluster import StrictRedisCluster
from aredis import StrictRedisCluster as AsyncStrictRedisCluster


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
redis_cluster = StrictRedisCluster.from_url(REDIS_CLUSTER_URL)
async_redis_cluster = AsyncStrictRedisCluster.from_url(REDIS_CLUSTER_URL)


async def operation1(key):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
        return await asyncio.wait_for(loop.run_in_executor(pool, redis_cluster.get, key), timeout=0.01)


async def operation2(key):
    return await asyncio.wait_for(async_redis_cluster.get(key), timeout=0.01)


def execute_operation1(key):
    try:
        return loop.run_until_complete(operation1(key))
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        pass


def execute_operation2(key):
    try:
        return loop.run_until_complete(operation2(key))
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        pass


res = execute_operation1('some_key')  # This one sometimes takes more than 10 ms in both success and timeout states
also_res = execute_operation2('some_key')  # This one abnormally consumes CPU and memory in production server
```

Am I doing something wrong?
I would appreciate it so much if someone could tell me if there is any way to do this properly or I am just wasting my time.

By the way it is the first time I am asking a question, so I am sorry for any mistakes I may have made and for my poor English as well.

Comment: You should probably add the server's code, together with how you run it, otherwise it may be hard to understand your issue. For now one thing I would advise is to start with only asynchronous code (no threads). Make the code as simple as possible and try to reproduce your problem. Another thing that you shouldn't have in your code is starting asynchronous tasks on your own (but I guess on your real code you don't). The server should run tasks for you (ie., your code shouldn't have any interaction with the event loop, no `loop.run_until_complete(...)` for example).

Comment: Make sure you are using this reference as a starting point : https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Async.html. I don't know uWSGI so I can't tell yet, but maybe you can try simpler approaches (like [starlette](https://www.starlette.io/) or any other ASGI oriented server).